# Append an element at the end of a list

Tags: list, ocaml, reason

How to append an element at the end of a list in ReasonML (the equivalent of `Array.concat` in JavaScript)?

Comment: Actually, that question is a bit more specific, so perhaps not quite a duplicate, but it does have some useful information.

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate a javascript array through e.g. bucklescript? In that case there may be a specific answer.

Comment: @ÉtienneMillon No, I am actually wondering what's the proper way to manipulate a list in reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Neil's answer is technically correct, it glosses over some details that you might want to consider before reaching for `append`; specifically that while adding an element to the beginning of a list is very cheap, **adding an element to the end is very expensive.**

To understand why, let's look at how a list is defined and constructed. The (conceptual) definition of a list is:

```ml
// Reason
type list('a) = Cons('a, list('a)) | Nil;
```

```ml
(* OCaml *)
type 'a list = Cons of 'a* 'a list | Nil
```

where `Nil` represents the end of a list (and by itself an empty list) and `Cons` represents a node in the list, containing an element of type `'a` and a pointer to the rest of the list (`list('a)`, OCaml: `'a list`).

If we took away all the syntax sugar and every helper function, you would have to construct a list like this:

```ml
// Reason
let myList = Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Nil)));
```

```ml
(* OCaml *)
let myList = Cons (1, Cons (2, Cons (3, Nil)))
```

To add an element to the head of this list then, we construct a node containing our new element and a pointer to the old list:

```ml
// Reason
let myBiggerList = Cons(0, myList);
```

```ml
(* OCaml *)
let myBiggerList = Cons (0, myList)
```

This is exactly the same as doing `[0, ...myList]` (OCaml: `0 :: myList`). If `myList` could change we wouldn't be able to do this, of course, but we know it doesn't since lists are immutable. That makes this very cheap, and for the same reason it's just as cheap to pop the head off, which is why you'll usually see list processing functions implemented using recursion, like this:

```ml
// Reason
let rec map = f =>
  fun | []         => []
      | [x, ...xs] => [f(x), ...map(f, xs)];
```

```ml
(* OCaml *)
let rec map f = function
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs -> (f x) :: (map f xs)
```

**Ok, so then why is it so expensive to add an element to the tail of the list?** If you look back at `myList`, adding an element to the end means replacing the final `Nil` with, say, `Cons(4, Nil)`. But then we need to replace `Cons(3, ...)` since that points to the old `Nil`, and `Cons(2, ...)` because it point to the old `Cons(3, ...)`, and so on through the entire list. And you have to do that every time you add an element. That quickly adds up.

**So what should you do instead?**

If you're adding to the end and either just iterating through it or always taking elements off the end, like you often would in JavaScript, you cam most likely just reverse your logic. Instead of adding to and taking off the end, add to and take off the beginning.

If you actually need a FIFO data structure, where elements are inserted at one end and taken off at the other, consider using a [Queue](https://reasonml.github.io/api/Queue.html) instead. In general, have a look at [this comparison of the performance characteristics of the standard containers](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/comparison_of_standard_containers.html).

Or if this is all a bit much and you'd really just like to do it like you're used to from JavaScript, just use an `array` instead of a `list`. You'll find all the functions you're familiar with in the [`Js.Array` module](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Array.html)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `List.append` or the `@` operator which is shorthand for `List.append`.

```
let lstA = [ 1 ];
let lstB = lstA @ [ 2 ];
let lstC = List.append(lstB, [ 3 ]);
```

Here is the documentation for List methods: https://reasonml.github.io/api/List.html

See a playground link here: https://reasonml.github.io/en/try.html?reason=DYUwLgBMDOYIIQLwQNoQIwQLoG4BQokMYAQklLAgAKoQBM2+hFYAwuQDICWsAdAIYAHQSAB2AEwAUxEgBpaAZmwBKfEA