# OCaml: list @ [x] vs x :: list

Tags: ocaml

I'm going through the [99 problems](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html) on OCaml.org and I noticed that the solutions to the problems in many cases (e.g. problems 9, 10, 11, 12 to name some) follow the pattern:

```
let rev list =
    let rec aux = function
       | [] -> []
       | h :: t -> h :: (aux t)
    in
    List.rev (aux list)
```

rather then simply gathering the elements with `@`:

```
let rec rev = function
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (rev t) @ [h]
```

*(The above example is trivially simplified and stupid, used just for illustration.)*

Is there any reason why using `::` and `List.rev` is better, then using `@` to append elements?

Comment: Does it apply to OCaml as well?

Comment: Yep, except for the syntax. The actual data structure is the same across pretty much any functional language. [I've actually written an answer on this already for Reason, but couldn't find it initially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49053903/7943564). I'll translate it to OCaml and post it as an answer here in a bit.

Comment: Oh, well I can't post an answer to a closed question, but I've updated the answer linked above with OCaml syntax.